# When rendering my animation, all frames exported will at some point become black

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, export

so as of lately when exporting an animation as a png sequence from Blender, every frame will at some point go black in the course of exporting, this will start at random frames and is more prevelant when exporting in higher resolutions (3840x2160 in my case)
Issue couldnt possibly lie in the compositions as they're basically all low poly, not including volumetrics, liquid sims or anything specifically hard that should be forcing this issue.
My hardware includes a 4090 and 128gb of ram and is running Blender 3.6.0 and like I said, I shouldnt have an issue with these comps.

This issue is messing with my work real bad as I'm trying to do overnight batch-renders and the renders will as explained at some random point come out all black, not from a specific point or frame or comp at all, it doesnt matter - but once it starts rendering black frames everything from there on out will be black, even when it goes to the next composition in the batch, those will all come out black.

If I do a PC restart the issue will be "reset" and I will be able to render the frames out until it at some point consistently starts spitting out black frames again. This can be after 5 frames or 200 frames, not dependent on what comp is being exported.

I just had a good IT guy do an thorough hardware/software scan and check the system for errors at the timecodes the frames began turning black and he found nothing that could explain this.

I'm used to eevee, which will at some point go black when vram is being exceeded, but this is using cycles and on frames that will come out after a restart or if I try again at lower resolutions, so why could this be?

When searching for the issue online, all I can find is answers about people not minding their render settings properly, a.i. hooking up the the compositor nodes right or accidentally ticking whether to use nodes/sequencer/compositor pipeline, but this is not my issue, the frames do come out right until a certain point.

Edit* I was asked to include a project file, which I will, but like I've said: this isnt dependent on this specific composition or the settings it has.

Blender comp: https://we.tl/t-ou7TGijQD8
Image of recent render warning: https://i.imgur.com/lBQGrpw.png

Comment: and how shall we now help you without knowing any of your settings? shall we guess? you searched already online...so i would recommend providing a blend file. Everything else can just be guesses, sorry.

Comment: Hey Chris, thank you for tuning in and helping me specify how others would be able to help, but I'm sorry that you felt it necessary to downvote me for this specific reason as well since as I tried to clarify in the post several times, this is not dependent on any specific comps or projects and therefore anything I'd upload would be kind of a distraction as I could change either of the settings and I'd still come across the issue.
I just upgraded to 3.6.2 and retried another brand new composition and after just 2 frames this time, were back to all black renders.

Comment: @FenderBendingBlenderRender Nevertheless, no matter if him downvoting your question was necessary or not, he is correct. Without knowing any settings or having your file to investigate it, when all we know is you basically already checked online  everything that might possibly go wrong - what new information do you expect us to suggest now?

Comment: All I'm trying to say is not to focus too much on the specific composition, but of course what else have you got to go off of, I agree.
Chris was very helpful and I immediately went toget a file to upload which is now in the bottom of the post.
I'm not here to argue or annoy anyone and I'm really sorry people are getting annoyed at my first ever post not being specific enough as I'll gladly correct that, I think thats what I was trying to say.
Again sorry everybody, a file is now uploaded and so is a recent error message that I've just found which prefaced the renders coming out all black

Comment: As it stands, if this issue appears after rendering some time and restarting the PC can reset it and you are insisting on not paying too much attention to the specific project and its settings - then to me it looks like a hardware issue on your side or a bug. Both are problems we cannot solve here because we are no Blender developers or in any way affiliated with the Blender organization, so these problems are considered off-topic on this site.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon, seriously, I wouldnt have known this if you hadn't stuck with me or my shitty post. This has really been messing with me lately and all the differing possible solutions can really be blinding and stressful

Answer (score 0):

After painfully investigating every dark corner of the internet for solutions and help, i ended up going through every bit of hardware as nothing was pointing towards blender settings or the pc-build itself being the issue.
I ended up discovering that it was due to an improperly installed fan in my otherwise mighty pc (it was literally shooting the hot air the wrong way, into the pc). Temperatures would only even out at 100°C+ while rendering the simplest of things and I'm guessing the high temperatures at some point would force the PC to shut off something Blender was accessing when rendering, thereby only exporting black frames.